# Как передать в C# массив строк из неуправляемой библиотеки?

Tags: c, pinvoke, c#

Привет!

Функция на C в DLL (которую я не могу менять), возвращает массив строк. Число элементов массива заранее неизвестно и может быть от 0 до 255.

```
#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE 255

//
// Возвращает длину массива (количество строк)
//
LONG GetStringArray(char **Array);
```

Реально ли вообще передать такие данные через P/Invoke? Если да, то как подступиться к задаче?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый удобный способ это по совету wow использовать Managed C++ и написать обертку оттуда. Можно и сделать чуть более криво примерно так(я добавил ссылку на входной массив, чтобы не использовать внешнюю функцию инициализации, которая необходима при вашем описании GetStringArray ) как:

С++

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LONG StringFunc(char** &data);

LONG StringFunc(char** & data)
{
    LONG count = 2;
    data = new char*[count];
    data[0] = new char[10];
    data[1] = new char[10];
    strcpy(data[0], "str1");
    strcpy(data[1], "bla bla1");
    return count;

}
```

С#:

```
[DllImport(@"..\..\..\..\debug\NativeDll.dll")]

public static extern LONG StringFunc(ref IntPtr data);

public static String[] CallNative()
{
  IntPtr ptr_start = IntPtr.Zero;
  LONG count = StringFunc(ref ptr_start);

  //массив указателей на строки
  IntPtr []ptr_strings =  new IntPtr[count];
  //копируем указатели на строки
  Marshal.Copy(ptr_start, ptr_strings, 0, count);
  String[] strings = new string[count];

  for (int i=0;i< count; i++)
  {
     strings[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr_strings[i]);                
  }

  return strings;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  String[] strings = CallNative();
  Array.ForEach(strings, s => Console.WriteLine(s));
}
```

Comment: спасибо за код

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите [PInvoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120). Это набор инструментов по работе с pinvoke.

Если окажется, что массив никак не протащить через pinvoke, можно написать библиотеку-обертку, которая будет преобразовывать неудобный формат в удобный. Например, можно в обертке принимать массив строк, а выдавать строки по отдельности.

Comment: полезный тулкит